# Вывод скрытого блока при вводе ссылки в строку браузера

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Вопрос заключается в следующем. На странице есть скрытый блок, который открывается при нажатии кнопки. Открывается как всплывающее окошко поверх всего остального содержимого. Возможно ли как-то в браузерную строку так ввести ссылку, чтобы этот блок сразу открылся? Скрыт блок средствами css (display:none;). Блоку присвоено id="inline".  Подскажите возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: а почему именно через браузерную строку? почему не через браузерную консоль?

Comment: или на c#   лучше ? или на питон ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вопросе автора не сказано, должно ли меняться содержимое окошка, поэтому самый простой вариант:

```
<style>
#popup {
    display:none;
}
#popup:target {
    display:block;
}
</style>

<div id="popup">Pop-up!</div>
```

При переходе на страницу index.html#popup, элемент с указанным в якоре ID (#popup) будет показан, так как срабатывает псевдо-селектор :target. Можно записывать в якорь любой id, и для него будет выполняться #id:target

Если вам нужно также менять текст в окошке, можно передавать его через GET или изменять сразу при генерации страницы (на PHP?), в таком случае даже можно сразу прописать дополнительный класс блоку, чтобы он был показан при загрузке страницы.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Очень помогли. Теперь выводит содержимое скрытого блока! Правда, не очень аккуратно, когда по ссылке переходишь, но думаю в css нужно просто подправить.